# How to play games which require a lot of power on old pcs like all the new strategic games and others?

Tags: windows-xp, graphics-card

I constantly hear this:

> Buy a power graphics card it only costs this and that and play any
>   games you want!

Well my question is if I have an old processor, say Pentium 4, with a lot of HDD for space to games and if I install a recognized powerful latest graphics card will I be able to play those strong games?

I.E. no matter what processor a system has, will the expensive graphics card take over and allow all current games to run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is wrong. Games are CPU and GPU dependent. That has to with a lot of factors, like resolution and such. Both can be the bottleneck to your system.

However, your old Pentium 4 - whichever it is - won't be able to power any of the newer games. In addition to that you may still be running an old AGP system on which you couldn't use all the newer PCI-E 2.0 Cards.

Comment: so can u please also tell that, if we need the cpu powerful also then what is the use of graphic card. Graphic cards also have a processor in them right?

Comment: @DoopyDoo Yes, the graphic card also has a "processor", however that one is computing all the graphic stuff, like its name indicates. But a game does not only need graphics, it needs a lot of other stuff to be calculated, like AI, some physics(also on GPU), ... and in addition it also has to feed the GPU with data.